# Cannot connect to mongoDB using Spring Data Reactive and Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: ssl, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-webflux, mongodb-atlas

I get the following error every time I trying to connect to MongoDB using Spring Data Reactive and Spring Boot 2.0.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No SSL support in java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel. For SSL support use com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory
        at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.<init>(AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.java:41)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.getStreamFactory(MongoClients.java:228)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:177)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:123)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:103)
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoClientFactory.createNetworkMongoClient(ReactiveMongoClientFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(ReactiveMongoClientFactory.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoAutoConfiguration.reactiveStreamsMongoClient(ReactiveMongoAutoConfiguration.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94536095.CGLIB$reactiveStreamsMongoClient$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94536095$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2171f816.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.ReactiveMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94536095.reactiveStreamsMongoClient(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:534)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:833)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:740)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:466)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:534)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:833)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:740)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:466)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:534)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1604)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:809)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:128)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:243)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:226)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:245)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

The error message tells me to use NettyStreamFactoryFactory for SSL support.  Does anyone have any examples on how to do this? The database I am trying to connect to is MongoDB Atlas, it strictly require a SSL connection.

Below is the rest of my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FlixMovieApiReactiveApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlixMovieApiReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }

    // Add Data
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initDatabase(MovieRepository repository) {

        // entire process blocking, done in beginning
        Flux<Movie> movieList = Flux.just(
                new Movie("movie1", "1", "movie1"),
                new Movie("movie2", "1", "movie2"),
                new Movie("movie3", "5", "movie3"),
                new Movie("movie4", "1", "movie4"),
                new Movie("movie5", "3", "movie5"),
                new Movie("movie6", "1", "movie6"),
                new Movie("movie7", "2", "movie7"),
                new Movie("movie8", "3", "movie8"),
                new Movie("movie9", "1", "movie9"),
                new Movie("movie10", "2", "movie10"),
                new Movie("movie11", "1", "movie11"),
                new Movie("movie12", "3", "movie12"),
                new Movie("movie13", "1", "movie13"),
                new Movie("movie14", "4", "movie14"),
                new Movie("movie15", "1", "movie15"),
                new Movie("movie16", "4", "movie16")
        );

        // delete then insert data.  blockLast(), allows something to subscribe to pipeline, block for last emitted element
        // data is written to the database.
        return args -> repository.deleteAll().thenMany(repository.save(movieList)).blockLast();
    }
}

@RestController
public class MovieRestController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/movies")
    public Flux<ResponseEntity<Movie>> list() {

        return movieService.list().map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/moviesByRating")
    public Flux<ResponseEntity<Movie>> findByRating(
            @RequestParam(value = "rating", required = false) final String rating) {

        return movieService.findByRating(rating)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));

    }

    @GetMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> read(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId) {

        return movieService.read(movieId)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK))
                .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> delete(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId) {

        return movieService.delete(movieId)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK))
                .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @PutMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> update(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId,
            @RequestBody final MovieRequest movieRequest) {

        return movieService.update(movieId, movieRequest)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK))
                .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

    }

    @PostMapping("/movies")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> create(
            @RequestBody final Mono<MovieRequest> movieRequest) {

        return movieService.create(movieRequest)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK))
                .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

    }

}

@Service
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Override
    public Flux<Movie> list(){
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Movie> findByRating(final String rating){
        return movieRepository.findByRating(rating);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> update(String id, MovieRequest movieRequest) {

       return movieRepository.findOne(id).map(existingMovie -> {

           if(movieRequest.getDescription() != null){
               existingMovie.setDescription(movieRequest.getDescription());
           }
           if(movieRequest.getRating() != null){
               existingMovie.setRating(movieRequest.getRating());
           }
           if(movieRequest.getTitle() != null) {
               existingMovie.setTitle(movieRequest.getTitle());
           }

           return existingMovie;

       }).then(movieRepository::save);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> create(Mono<MovieRequest> movieRequest) {

        return movieRequest.map(newMovie -> {

            Movie movie = new Movie();

            if(newMovie.getDescription() != null){
                movie.setDescription(newMovie.getDescription());
            }
            if(newMovie.getRating() != null){
                movie.setRating(newMovie.getRating());
            }
            if(newMovie.getTitle() != null) {
                movie.setTitle(newMovie.getTitle());
            }

            return movie;

        }).then(movieRepository::save);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> read(String id) {
        return movieRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> delete(String id) {
        return movieRepository.findOne(id)
                .flatMap(oldValue -> movieRepository.delete(id).then(Mono.just(oldValue)))
                .singleOrEmpty();
    }
}

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Movie, String> {

    Flux<Movie> findByRating(String rating);
}

@Document
public class Movie {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String rating;
    private String description;

    public Movie(String title, String rating, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Movie() {
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

---

spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
          uri: mongodb://admin:xxxxxx@movie-shard-00-00-xfzg4.mongodb.net:27017,movie-shard-00-01-xfzg4.mongodb.net:27017,movie-shard-00-02-xfzg4.mongodb.net:27017/movie?ssl=true&replicaSet=Movie-shard-0&authSource=admin

management:
  context-path: /admin

server:
  port: 8080
```

Below is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.flix.movie</groupId>
    <artifactId>flix-movie-api-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>flix-movie-api-reactive</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot using Non-Blocking Reactive Spring Web MVC and Spring Data MongoDB</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>flix</docker.image.prefix>
        <docker.spotify.plugin.version>0.4.5</docker.spotify.plugin.version>
        <swagger.version>2.4.0</swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies-web-reactive</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Package as a docker image -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.spotify.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <imageTags>
                        <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                    </imageTags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

**in connection String**

xxxx?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true&streamType=netty

**or Via MongoClientSettings**

```
EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();  // make sure application shuts this down

@Bean
    public MongoClient getClient()
    {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .clusterSettings(ClusterSettings.builder()
                                          .hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress()))
                                          .build())
                        .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder()
                                          .eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup).build())
                        .sslSettings(SslSettings.builder()
                                          .enabled(true)
                                          .build())
                        .build());
    }

    @PreDestroy
        public void shutDownEventLoopGroup() {
            eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
```

[Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver-async/tutorials/ssl/)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a Spring Data Mongo and/or Spring Boot issue.
At first it seems Spring Boot is giving the appropriate information to the Spring Data Mongo client configuration.

Could you create an issue on [the dedicated issue tracker for Spring Data Mongo](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/)?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just created the issue in your issue tracker.

Comment: Could you edit your question to reflect that with a link? Or you can answer your own question if this problem was resolved in the issue itself. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is related to `MongoClient` configuration. SSL requires netty and needs to be configured in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

As mp911de mentioned above, adding Netty dependency in your pom will solve the problem.

For me, adding the spring-boot-starter-webflux resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's the MongoClient who is responsible for managing the connection. In your case it is the default unprotected one, so if you have security enabled on your Mongo instance he will bounce back.

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class MongoConfig : AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration() {

override fun reactiveMongoClient(): MongoClient = MongoClients.create()

override fun getDatabaseName(): String = "mydb"

}
```

This is my configuration for reactive mongo in spring boot 2 M4. You can customize your client via MongoClients methods or appropriate constructor.